# PDF generator from php

Tags: php, unicode, pdf-generation

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('..\..\MBLateefi.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 30);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 12);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->Cell(110 ,30,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(23 ,5,'تاريخ',0,1,'R');
$pdf->Output();
```

[image: Result here]

this script i run from TCPDF/examples/  please help!  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: i just wan to result like تاريخ in PDF

Comment: Maybe the font you are using doesn't have a ر glyph for that codepoint?

Comment: The font seems to have it (http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/MB-Lateefi-Regular), but I suspect 'TrueTypeUnicode' could be the issue.